# getting error while returning STATUS command result to LIST in IMAP

Tags: imap

I am trying to query IMAP Server to LIST mailboxes with Status command.
That is, i am returning STATUS COMMAND result to List command input and trying to list all the mailboxes with STATUS.

i tried.

```
A LIST "" % RETURN (STATUS (MESSAGES UNSEEN))
A BAD [CLIENTBUG] LIST Additional arguments found after last expected argument
```

But i am getting error from IMAP Server.

i checked following RFC and followed.

http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/draft-melnikov-imapext-status-in-list-00.pdf

```
Examples
 C: A01 LIST "" % RETURN (STATUS (MESSAGES UNSEEN))
 S: * LIST () "." "INBOX"
 S: * STATUS "INBOX" (MESSAGES 17 UNSEEN 16)
 S: * LIST () "." "foo"
 S: * STATUS "foo" (MESSAGES 30 UNSEEN 29)
```

Note : 
if i ran STATUS and LIST command separately working fine. when combining like above getting Error from server. pls help me out...

Answer (score 1):

For that to work you need support for both RFCs [5258](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5258) and [5819](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5819). You're probably using a server that supports neither of them.